# Best way to put delay after calling javascript functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery to call some javascript functions with a delay between them.
Also I'm using [Jquery Wait](http://docs.jquery.com/Cookbook/wait)

When I call below function,all functions are called recpectively,there are no delays between each other.

```
$(this)
.call(f1)
.wait(5000)
.call(f2)
.wait(5000)
.call(f3);
```

Here **call** function calls some function as I did

```
$.fn.call = function (f) {
    if (f)
        f();

    return this;
};
```

What am i doing wrong ?
How can i achieve something like this ? 
Thank you

Comment: What, exactly, isn't working here?

Comment: functions are called one by one,there are no delays between them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to call a function every 5 seconds use

```
setTimeout(function(){f1},5000);
setTimeout(function(){f2},10000);
setTimeout(function(){f2},15000);
```

if you want to call each function 5 seconds after the last one terminated use

```
setTimeout(function(){f1;setTimeout(function(){f2;setTimeout(function(){f3},5000);},5000);},5000);
```

Comment: setTimeout() will call each function once. To call a function repeatedly, use setInterval().

Comment: is there a way to achieve this in jquery ? i mean like i did

Comment: why do you need jQuery? jQuery is just a javascript framework and will work with this

Comment: I know what jquery is.For later use,I will have animations work with this code,that's why i should stick with jquery.Your implementation is also correct +1

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `wait()` from that cookbook; [delay()](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) is built-in and appears to have the same functionality. But either function involves adding something to jQuery's internal queue of effects and then removing it after a timeout expires, i.e. it's not a sleep statement, so it's not going to wait around before returning.

If you want to use `delay()` or `wait()`, you should make `call()` enqueue the function with [queue()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/). Just sketching, but something like:

```
$.fn.call = function(f) {
    if (f) {
        $(this).queue(function() {
            f();
            $(this).dequeue();
        }
    }
    return this;
}
```

Then I'd expect your code to work the way you intend.

Comment: Well, it was just a sketch to get you in the right direction, insofar as using wait/delay is concerned. I haven't actually tried it, so it might take some tweaking. Look carefully at the documentation for queue(), and try some of their examples.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that calls in sequence an array of function:

```
$.fn.callFn = function(fns, delay) {
    var fn, that = this;
    if(fns.length > 0){
        fn = fns.shift()
        fn && fn();
        setTimeout(function(){
            that.callFn(fns, delay);
        }, delay);
    }
    return this;
};
```

And you would call it like that:

```
$(this).callFn([f1, f2, f3], 2000);
```

Comment: I will have animations work with my code($(this)
.call(f1).wait(5000).call(f2).wait(5000).animate(...).wait(1000).call(f3);),that's why i should stick with jquery.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#box').slideUp(300).delay(800).fadeIn(400);

/* .delay = wait time = 800 (this means it will wait 800/1000 of a second/ "1000 = 1 second") */
```